# Downloading from wget - folder issue

Tags: localhost, wget

I have a website - http://myradio1.localhost and the directory is currently empty.

The virtual host works fine, no issues there.

This is my command I'm using to download the site via wget:

> wget --user-agent="Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)"
>   -r --convert-links -p -P "C:\www\public_html\myradio1" "http://www.compassfm.co.uk"

It downloads the site perfectly, except for one thing, it always renders it like this when downloaded:

http://myradio1.localhost/www.compassfm.co.uk

which is *not* what I want to happen. I want it just to download to the folder, so it can run as http://myradio1.localhost, without me having to move the files out of the domain folder after download has completed.

How can I get wget to download all files, but without creating the domain as a folder, basically?

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You need the parameter `--no-host-directories` or `-nH`, e.g.

```
wget --user-agent="Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)" --no-host-directories -r --convert-links -p -P "C:\www\public_html\myradio1" "http://www.compassfm.co.uk"
```

From the manual:

> **-nH**
>    **--no-host-directories**
>              Disable generation of host-prefixed directories.  By default,
>              invoking Wget with **-r http://fly.srk.fer.hr/** will create a
>              structure of directories beginning with fly.srk.fer.hr/.  This
>              option disables such behavior.

Comment: askubuntu's answer sets a new default (with alias in `.bashrc`) without needing to type the command each time: [how to change wget default directory](https://askubuntu.com/a/213529/1024340)